# I am trying to set height for header and footer in section through code but it doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I tried to set height for footer and header for section in table view through code but it doesn't work . When I do it from storyboard , it works fine .

This is my code

```swift
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable : UITableView!
    
    let spacing : CGFloat = 20
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTable.delegate = self
        myTable.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension MyTableViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Random text"
        cell.accessoryType = .detailButton
        return cell
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return spacing
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return spacing
    }
}
```

Output of the code:

[image: Output of the code]

I want to have some padding to the cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `UITableViewDelegate` will return nil in `viewForHeaderInSection` (the same as with the footer) if you aren't conforming. In the storyboard, you can directly drag a cell or view, it represents dynamic prototypes, that's why it works until you add table's Delegate/DataSource.

Add this delegate method:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    //... some configurations here if needed
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .orange
    //... some configurations here if needed
    return view
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful answer ! It worked and I didn't know this .

Comment: Yeah, no worries.